# Using classes in Python (similar to data structures in MATLAB) to store player stats

Tags: python, matlab, data-structures

So here is the code that I have thus far:

```
from builtins import any

class Player:

    Name = ' '
    O = 0
    H = 0
    HBP = 0
    BB = 0
    K = 0
    ROE = 0    

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

#Open text file with play-by-play data
file = open('Tennessee Tech vs Jacksonville State 04092017.txt', 'r')
lines = file.readlines()
for s in lines:

    #Finds the name of the player
    player = s.split()[0]
    x = Player(player)

    #Confirms that a given string corresponds to an at-bat
    if any('(' in x for x in s)==True:
        count = s[s.find('(')+1:s.find(')')]

    #Identifies the event that occurred
    event = s.split()[1]
    out_ids = ['popped', 'flied', 'fouled', 'struck', 'grounded', 'lined']
    hit_ids = ['homered', 'singled', 'doubled', 'tripled']
    hbp_ids = ['hit by pitch']
    bb_ids = ['walked']
    strikeout_ids = ['struck']
    error_ids = ['reached']
    if any(event in x for x in out_ids)==True:
        x.O += 1
        # print(player + ' ' + count + ' ' + 'O')
    if any(event in x for x in hit_ids)==True:
        x.H += 1
        # print(player + ' ' + count + ' ' + 'H')
    if any(event in x for x in hbp_ids)==True:
        x.HBP += 1
        # print(player + ' ' + count + ' ' + 'HBP')
    if any(event in x for x in bb_ids)==True:
        x.BB += 1
        # print(player + ' ' + count + ' ' + 'BB')
    if any(event in x for x in strikeout_ids)==True:
        x.K += 1
        # print('on ' 'K')
    if any(event in x for x in error_ids)==True:
        x.ROE += 1
        # print(player + ' ' + count + ' ' + 'ROE')
```

And here is an idea of a few lines in the .txt file that I am parsing:

```
JUNIOR popped up to 2b (0-0).
PUTZIG flied out to cf (1-1 BS).
STROHSCHEIN fouled out to 2b (1-1 FB).
DANIEL,Clayt fouled out to 1b (2-1 BFB).
ROBINSON,Cha struck out swinging (1-2 SBFFS).
REYNOLDS,A. grounded out to 1b unassisted (1-0 B).
FLICK singled to right field (1-2 KBF).
CHAMBERS flied out to cf to right center (2-1 KBB).
```

Essentially, I am trying to create a data structure for every given player, then store their stats in that structure as well.

For example, let's say player JUNIOR popped out, therefore I would like to add 1 to the counter for his Outs (e.g. Junior.Outs = 1). If you then grounded out later in the game, then I would like to add another to this counter (e.g. Junior.Outs should now read 2 if called). There are some other categories as well, but I am relatively new to working with classes in Python.

Thanks in advance for any guidance!

Comment: So, what is your question? It sounds like you are asking for a tutorial on Python classes.

Comment: As an aside, don't do `if any(...)==True:`, just `if any(...):` suffices

Comment: Thanks for your comments on any (...), I will make that adjustment. As far as Python classes, I am just curious if I am on the right track here or if I am approaching this incorrectly.